# Добавление JPanel из другого класса

Tags: java, java-8, awt

хочу добавить на `JPanel` кнопки, а потом отобразить все это через главный класс, подскажите, как правильно оформить.

```
package com.company;

import res.Source;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JFrame { //главный класс в который хочу вставить JPanel
    public Main(){
        Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        setSize(800, 400);
        setLocation(sSize.width/2 - 400, sSize.height/2 - 200);
        setResizable(false);
        add(new Source());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }
}


package res;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Source extends JPanel { //класс откуда хочу вставить JPanel
    private JPanel panel;
    private char x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3;

    public Source(){
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        field();
    }

    public void field(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        panel.setBounds(10,10, 720,720);
        panel.add(new JButton("sdf"));
    }
}
```

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

либо в метод field добавить:

```
public void field(){
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    panel.setBounds(10,10, 720,720);
    panel.add(new JButton("sdf"));
    add(panel);
}
```

Либо это всё счастье добавить в сам конструктор Source панели:

```
public Source(){
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    setBounds(10,10, 720,720);
    add(new JButton("sdf"));
}
```

Comment: Хмм, а как управлять ее размером? нужен Layout и как его добавить?

Comment: Немного изменим конструктор класса Source:

public Source(){
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    setBounds(10,10, 720,720);
    JButton btn = new JButton("sdf");//создаём кнопку
    btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));//Задаём ей размер(ширина, высота)
    add(btn);//Добавляем её на нашу Source панель.
}

Layout это определённые правила, по которым будут располагаться компоненты. Их можно устанавливать на любой JPanel отдельно или на сам JFrame методом setLayout(нужный Layout). Почитайте подробнее про java swing layouts.